# Contour of (x, y, z) list values

Tags: python, plot, contour

In python I can get a contour with:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p


def main():

    delta = 1
    x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, delta)
    y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, delta)

    len_x, len_y = len(x), len(y)
    z = np.random.rand(len_x, len_y)

    cs = p.contour(x, y, z)
    p.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)

    p.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: ss]

how I can get the contour of a list of `(x, y, z)` values?

```
    delta = 1
    x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, delta)
    y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, delta)

    values = [(x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1), (x3, y3, z3)]

    cs = p.contour(x, y, values)
```

### EDIT

the list have few values, less of len_x * len_y

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just trying to figure out how to feed `contour()` with your `values` list:

```
p.contour(*zip(*values))
```

Comment: but if the list  only have three values, this code works ?

Comment: If the list has a single tuple with three values in it, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata


def main():

    p.figure()

    x = [1, 1, 2, 2]
    y = [1, 2, 1, 2]
    z = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2]

    p.scatter(x, y, color='k')

    # define grid.
    xi = np.linspace(0, 3, 1000)
    yi = np.linspace(0, 3, 1000)
    zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='nn')
    cs = p.contour(xi, yi, zi, 10)
    p.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=12)
    p.colorbar()

    p.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: ss]